# Creating a new Activity, makes a whole new application?

Tags: java, android

Im new to android, and when i read "Create New Activity" i was under the impression it creates a new "Window/Layout/Screen".

When i start making my own application i see

> Main.java

is one application and

> SecondActivity.java

is another app in my Emulators menu?

Why is that and how can i go about making one app with multiple windows as apposed to multiple applications essentially?

> Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ryan.bidorbuyapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/bidorbuy_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchResults"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_results"
            android:parentActivityName=".FullscreenActivity"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.ryan.bidorbuyapp.FullscreenActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

thanks

Comment: Can you post your manifest.xml maybe?

Comment: so if i remove <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" this will solve the issue? in one of them that is?

Comment: From just one of the activities, yes

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! something so simple....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your AndroidManifest.xml there is the problem. Your activities have Launcher between it's tags. Only one activity must have LAUNCHER tag

Only one activity must have

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: @Петър Петров -  `Only one activity must have `. Its not necessary.

Comment: i agree with you, i mean that must have one launcher in this case

Answer (score 0):

You should understand what is an Activity before starting to developing an android application. You can think an activity as a page in web. There can be one or more and every activity includes their own contents.

When you create a new activity in your project, you should navigate by doing some operations in another activity. `Intent` helps you at this point to navigate one activity to the another.

Your problem is that, you should check your AndroidManifest.xml file. Please check the declaration of intent here. I think you will solve it after making a search about `Intent`.